# mongodb: how to express "schema"?

Tags: mongodb

Once many teams work with the same mongodb database there needs to be some way to express what each document may contain. Otherwise the document will end be having "email", "mail", "email_addr" fields added by each team. What's the best way to represent this for the purpose of communication across teams?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, the best way is what the team is most comfortable with. It can be UML, whiteboard drawings, XML mappings, model code files, maybe even haiku poems :)

I personally prefer using an ODM (mongoid). It encourages you to specify all fields in the model class. Then you just need one glance at it to understand the schema.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is create your Objects first in a set of commons that all team members import into their projects.  If you change schema design, you update Commons project and all team members import latest.

It's more about process and project management and less about technology given Mongo's schema-less design.  One thing we find helpful is design your Tests first and lately, SoapUI and LoadUI have been excellent tools.  Once you define your tests, it can stub the returns for you and produces HTML documentation you can distribute to team.

Check out:  http://www.soapui.org/REST-Testing/working-with-rest-services.html

Answer (score 1):

When you create collection, just add to it some first "reference" object that would have all the fields/sub-objects that object of this collection can possibly have and use it as "schema". You can even write validator that would check that new objects conform to this reference object.